# Solr highlight bug with useFastVectorHighlighter?

Tags: solr

When I use `solr` with `useFastVectorHighlighter = true`, I get some errors.

Here is my query log:

```
[user] webapp= path=/select params={mm=1&hl.tag.post=</b>&qf=firstName+nickName^5+lastName&hl.tag.pre=<b>&wt=javabin&hl=true&version=2&rows=100&defType=dismax&hl.highlightMultiTerm=true&hl.useFastVectorHighlighter=true&start=0&q=a+bc&hl.boundaryScanner=breakIterator} hits=3767 status=500 QTime=266 ,someone can help me? but query with abc(without blank) is ok.



java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -6
        at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.lucene.search.vectorhighlight.BaseFragmentsBuilder.makeFragment(BaseFragmentsBuilder.java:166)
        at org.apache.lucene.search.vectorhighlight.BaseFragmentsBuilder.createFragments(BaseFragmentsBuilder.java:115)
        at org.apache.lucene.search.vectorhighlight.FastVectorHighlighter.getBestFragments(FastVectorHighlighter.java:186)
        at org.apache.solr.highlight.DefaultSolrHighlighter.doHighlightingByFastVectorHighlighter(DefaultSolrHighlighter.java:532)
        at org.apache.solr.highlight.DefaultSolrHighlighter.doHighlighting(DefaultSolrHighlighter.java:399)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.component.HighlightComponent.process(HighlightComponent.java:131)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:186)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:129)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1376)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:365)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:260)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the `BaseFragmentsBuilder` (had to check if the startOffset is larger than the endOffset) and created a patched JAR in our project Artifactory. Excluded the original JAR with `packagingExcludes` and added the patched one. I used the`<version>` Tag like `3.6.1_patched` a classifier would be more Maven likely.

Well [here is a link to my patched JAR.](http://www.sendspace.com/file/bqhfb0)

Mainly I did some range checking on the offsets. The if-statement fixes the bug.

```
int startOffset = to.getStartOffset() - modifiedStartOffset[0] < 0 ? 0 : to.getStartOffset() - modifiedStartOffset[0];
int endOffset = to.getEndOffset() - modifiedStartOffset[0] > src.length()-1 ? src.length()-1 : to.getEndOffset() - modifiedStartOffset[0];
if (srcIndex < startOffset) {
    fragment
    .append(encoder.encodeText(src.substring(srcIndex, startOffset)))
    .append( getPreTag( preTags, subInfo.getSeqnum() ) )
    .append( encoder.encodeText( src.substring(startOffset, endOffset ) ) )
    .append( getPostTag( postTags, subInfo.getSeqnum() ) );
}
srcIndex = endOffset;
```

Hopefully this will help you with the use of the FastVectorHighlighter. 
Cheers
Marcel

Comment: posted a bugreport in the [SOLR JIRA system](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-4137)